# Наставить рога

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "наставить рога"? Почему обманутых мужей называют "рогоносцами"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну "рогоносец" уже вторично, исходно именно "наставить рога", даже "рога выросли". Причем вполне конретные - оленьи. А вообще этимология не совсем понятная, явно заимствованная из французского(?), где отсылает к рыцарским временам и относится на счет оленей, некоторые виды которых отращивают рога к сезону брачных поединков и сбрасывают после. Именно такое обозначение "олень" (или лось) часто используют как синоним "рогоносца".

По одной из версий связано с обычаем вешать оленьи рога в знак привилегии на ворота замков, чей хозяин имел в женах любовницу короля. Но недостоверно. Подобные объяснения, варьируемые в частностях, встречаются довольно часто. Но на самом деле все такие объяснения, безотносительно даже к их достоверности, не отвечают на главный вопрос - почему именно оленьи рога испольовались для такой метки.

Есть еще одно объяснение (еще менее достоверное), что рог звал в поход мужа, а походы в те временя продолжались годами. У жены было время "наставить рога", поясА верности, как известно, не очень-то помогали.

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время существуют четыре версии происхождения выражения "наставить рога":
1) Византийский император Андроник Комнин (1183-1185) разрешал мужьям тех женщин, с которыми имел любовные связи, охотиться в его зверинце. На воротах тех, кто имел такое преимущество, выставлялись оленьи рога. Шутя о таком человеке говорили, что у него рога на лбу. Выражение попало в русский язык через посредство греческого или французского языка.
2) Слово заимствовано из немецкого и восходит к военному снаряжению древних германцев.
Провожая мужа на войну, жена надевала ему на голову шлем с рогами. На языке женщин надеть мужу рога означало снарядить мужа в поход и остаться свободной.
3) Из мифа об Актеоне, который подсматривал за купающейся богиней Дианой и за это был превращен ею в оленя. Актеон употребляется в значении "рогоносец, обманутый муж".
4) В немецком императорском указе 1427 г. запрещается пребывание в армии с женой; преступивший этот запрет должен был носить рога.

Comment: Последние два варианта - ни к селу, ни к городу. Или исчез какой-то связующий элемент.

Answer (score 0):

1. Более подходит вариант про Андроника: ведь выражение "рога наставила" означает, что ЗАКОННАЯ жена осознанно изменяет мужу, УЖЕ переспала и продолжает спать с другим мужиком, обманывает мужа в постели с любовником. Гулящая супруга, короче. В других версиях именно этого смысла нет.
2. Проводить мужа в поход — не значит изменить ему. И, потом, немки, наоборот, считались в те времена самыми верными и любящими женами.
3. То, что богиня превратила подглядывающего Актеона в оленя, — тоже не то. Богиня ж ему не жена, и он ей не муж, получается, богиня  не обманула его, как мужа, тайком переспав с другими, изменяя направо и налево. То есть: по смыслу получается совсем не то, значение поговорки эта легенда не оправдывает...
4. Муж взял с собой в поход жену и за это носит рога. Опять же: где тут измена жены? Нет. Совсем даже наоборот: верная жена не покинула мужа. По смыслу и значению эта версия опять же не подходит.
   Вариант с сатиром: это мифическое существо, поэтому в реале с ним никто мужу изменить не мог. Не подходит.
   ВЫВОД: значит, Андроник.